# Xcode 7 Swift 2 should I use a button font or Image?

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton

I'm totally new to Xcode and I'm trying to write a very simple app.

On my main screen, basically I load three buttons vertically/centered. I also have an Image for each button. When I press (touch down), the image changes to another image (just to show its selected).

The images that I'm using are nothing but different colored font with a border line. Should I just use the same font in the button and change it to a different color when pressed or use images to show the button is selected/unselected? Does this have an impact on the app (load image) each time a button is pressed?

Can I have different sizes of the button loaded based on different iphone? Is yes, how can I do that?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Wain mentioned the performance difference should be insignificant. I do agree through that changing the font color is probably easier to maintain and change in code.

Change the font in your code by using this example in your IBAction method:

```
labelName.font = UIFont(name: "systemFont", size: 30)
```

Concerning your other question about different sizes on different devices, you should do this by setting constraints. I recommended you to read Apple's auto layout guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraintsinInterfaceBuidler.html

But the essence is that you set the width and height of the button based on its distance to other elements in your UI or the edges of the screen. If you for example want your button to be 25 points from the left and right edges of the screen, this will naturally mean that the button will be wider on a iPhone 6 Plus, since the screen is bigger and the button will have to be wider to be 25 points of the edges.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

It's all a trade off, but if the button contents are simple it's easy to do in code and it reduces future maintenance. If you use images you need to follow the standard @1x, @2x, @3x approach so you'll have multiple copies of the same images at different sizes. You won't really notice a performance difference in either case, the images are generally cached for you (if you load then using the name) and they aren't large images.

Comment: I did have to create some images. I think I'll stick to the buttons and not load images. Appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Loading assets into a UIButton for different states has more impact on memory than changing the Fonts color. The impact is so small though, that it is unlikely you will ever notice.
So I'd say this one is up to you. Keep in mind though that you sacrifice a lot of flexibility by using static images.

For your second question:
Yes it is possible to vary the size of UI Elements depending on the screen Size / iPhone / iPad Version.
For that have a look at Apples Autolayout.